# Codeigniter redirect function is having error

Tags: codeigniter, helper

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/adityanamansingh/kings.adityanamansingh.com/system/core/Exceptions.php:271)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 564

Backtrace:

File: /home/adityanamansingh/kings.adityanamansingh.com/application/controllers/admin/Login.php
Line: 34
Function: redirect

File: /home/adityanamansingh/kings.adityanamansingh.com/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Why am I receiving this error in my code.

Comment: check if anything is printed on the Login.php or uri_helper.php e.g echo, any text typed or print .from top to bottom .

Comment: @SandeepModak Thank You but there is no use of any echo, print_r or var_dump on either of them

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy for everyone if you share your code. 
You can look at this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26311455/8336118) which says

> The error occurs when you have started outputting anything before
>   header redirect in PHP code. For example, check out any white spaces
>   after or before PHP tags, HTML tags printing before starting of PHP
>   tags or any output or debugging before the redirect function.

Also check for blank line before and after your closing php tag.

Hope it helps. Happy coding